# How to check if a recipient has an automatic reply configured before email is sent?

Tags: java, spring, email, outlook

I have Spring application which sends emails by using java code.

**Is it possible to detect if recipient has configured an automatic reply from code?**

For example Outlook shows during composing emails which of the recipients has configured auto reply.

[image]

**UPDATE:** Lets assune that all recipients are using the same Microsoft Mail Server.

Comment: If you were that application how would _you_ know a recipient has an automatic reply configured _before_ sending an email?

Comment: It's possible if you could check for headers of reply.

Comment: You're trying to predict the future here. You can't. You can only detect things after they happen.

Comment: @EJP, outlook has mechanism for retrieving this data before email is sent

Comment: @ Raju Sharma , you are talking about the actual auto reply message. But I need to get this data before sending it.

Comment: @Thomas, It is possible somehow for outlook.

Comment: @Speise What mechanism? Citation please. And if you know the answer, why are you asking the question?

Comment: I suspect that outlook only detects this for recipients on the same mailserver, not for recipients of other mailservers.

Comment: Please try it again with an email address you've never sent an email to and that is hosted somewhere else. You won't see that.

Comment: What has "The recipient is outside your organization" to do with an automatic reply?

Comment: A screenshot is not a citation, especially when completely and utterly irrelevant.

Comment: @baao, EJP, Sorry guys, was wrong screenshot.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Lets assume we are talking about some specific mailserver. Is there any possibility to get info from there about recipients?

Comment: No. As that isn't part of the protocol, outlook uses it own mechanism to communicate to the Exchange server which probably has this functionality build in.

Comment: @Speise Let's *state* clearly exactly *which* 'specific mail server' we're talking about, and provide some proper support for our assertions, instead of merely contradicting everybody.

Comment: However I don't think that this is an actual outlook feature. I haven't seen outlook writing smileys `:)` That's something intern to your organization accounts

Comment: @baao, the smile is the part of auto reply message`

Comment: @EJP, lets assume we are talking about Microsoft mail server. Update to the question is provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `GetMailTips` EWS verb - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877060(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: As I understand Microsoft Mail Server expose some SOAP service by using which I can retrieve mail tips data?

Comment: Correct, Exchange server exposes GetMailTips as well as tons of other functionality as a web service. See the link above.